# Generate XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to generate a XML file using PHP having the following structure. This file is a structure of a quiz, where each question has five answers. Question and answer texts are enclosed in CDATA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuizMaster>
<header version="0.36" exportVersion="1" />
    <data>
        <quiz>
            <autostart>false</autostart>
            <forms activated="false" position="0" />
            <questions>
                <question answerType="single">
                    <questionText><![CDATA[What is the city?]]></questionText>
                    <correctMsg />
                    <incorrectMsg />
                    <answers>
                        <answer points="1" correct="true">
                            <answerText html="false"><![CDATA[Kolkata]]></answerText>
                        </answer>
                        <answer points="1" correct="false">
                            <answerText html="false"><![CDATA[Delhi]]></answerText>
                        </answer>
                        <answer points="1" correct="false">
                            <answerText html="false"><![CDATA[Mumbai]]></answerText>
                        </answer>
                        <answer points="1" correct="false">
                            <answerText html="false"><![CDATA[Chennai]]></answerText>
                        </answer>
                        <answer points="1" correct="false">
                            <answerText html="false"><![CDATA[Goa]]></answerText>
                        </answer>
                    </answers>
                </question>
            </questions>
        </quiz>
    </data>
</QuizMaster>
```

I've tried the following PHP code. It starts giving error from the second answer (// Answer 2) where *attributes* for the *answer* element is declared. The error is like **Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Attribute already exists in C:\wamp\www\quiz stack.php on line 46**. I have already incorporated this kind coding in a few other places in this project but in all the cases, each question had only one answer.

```
<?php
class SimpleXMLExtended extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function addCData($cdata_text)
    {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($this);
        $no = $node->ownerDocument;
        $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text));
    }
}

$xmlFile = 'quiz_file.xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLExtended('<QuizMaster/>');
// header
$xml->header = NULL;
$xml->header->addAttribute('version', '0.36');
$xml->header->addAttribute('exportVersion', '1');
$xml->data = NULL;
// quiz
$xml->data->quiz = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->autostart = ('false');
// forms
$xml->data->quiz->forms = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->forms->addAttribute('activated', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->forms->addAttribute('position', '0');
// Question Start
$xml->data->quiz->questions = NULL;
// Question answer loop starts here
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->addAttribute('answerType', 'single');
// Question text
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->questionText = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->questionText->addCData('What is the     city?');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->correctMsg = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->incorrectMsg = NULL;
// Answers start
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers = NULL;
// Answer 1
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('points', '1');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('correct', 'true');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addCData('Kolkata');
// Answer 2
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('points', '1');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addCData('Delhi');
// Answer 3
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('points', '1');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addCData('Mumbai');
// Answer 4
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('points', '1');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addCData('Chennai');
// Answer 5
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('points', '1');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText = NULL;
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->answer->answerText->addCData('Goa');
// Write Data
$xml->saveXML($xmlFile);
?>
```

If I comment out the offending two lines (where *addAttribute* is applied to *answer* element) from each answer except *answer 1*, then the file is generated but with only one answer that contains the text in *Answer 5*.

Can anyone suggest if there is any workaround for this problem without changing  **SimpleXMLElement** object?

Comment: Line 46 is just one line below the comment  _// Asnwer 2_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a code that was ment to be used with a single `answer` node, you should be adding childs instead:

```
$answer2 = $xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->addChild('answer');
$answer2->addAttribute('points', '1');
$answer2->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$answer2->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$answer2->answerText->addCData('Delhi');

$answer3 = $xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->addChild('answer');
$answer3->addAttribute('points', '1');
$answer3->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$answer3->answerText->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$answer3->answerText->addCData('Mumbai');
```

Use this approach for all your answers (event the first answer).

And now, taking a deeper look, you may have to use the `addChild` method for your `answerText` node also:

```
$answer3Text = $answer3->addChild('answerText');
$answer3Text->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$answer3Text->addCData('Mumbai');
```

So, the code should look like this for all your answers:

```
$answer3 = $xml->data->quiz->questions->question->answers->addChild('answer');
$answer3->addAttribute('points', '1');
$answer3->addAttribute('correct', 'false');
$answer3Text = $answer3->addChild('answerText');
$answer3Text->addAttribute('html', 'false');
$answer3Text->addCData('Mumbai');
```

Comment: Incorporating this code is producing following error:  
**Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Unable to locate parent Element in C:\wamp\www\quiz stack.php on line 41**. This line contents _addAttribute_ of _answerText_. Also as the defined class _SimpleXMLExtended_ is not getting a parameter, subsequently, that is also producing more errors.

Comment: Yes, your this coding worked properly. Thanks for the help.